# Remove data from the STDIN stream buffer of another TTY session

Tags: bash, tty, stdin, streams

I encountered a problem the other day while running multiple `tty` sessions in separate terminal windows. I was running a expensive disk access command and was waiting for it to return. Meanwhile I was working in another `tty` session in a separate window in my graphical desktop environment.

Inadvertently I focused the terminal that was running the disk access command (basically a `cp` command) and typed the following into the terminal thinking I was going to enter it into my other window:

<kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Based on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178989/is-it-safe-to-type-another-command-into-stdin-while-the-previous-command-is-writ) I knew that the data was now sitting in the `STDIN` data stream buffer waiting to be run immediately upon the return of the first `cp` command. And as you know I just told the command to run again :/ .

### The Question

Since I had some time (this command was taking > 30 mins to return), is there a way I could have flushed these characters out of the `STDIN` buffer of that `tty` before bash reran the process it was finishing?

Or is there another way, other than trying to flush data out of the file stream buffer of another bash instance, that I could avoid having the data evaluated as soon as the process that I was waiting on finished?

Comment: You can write a small C program to do this, using tcflush: see [How can I flush unread data from a tty input queue on a UNIX system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938882/how-can-i-flush-unread-data-from-a-tty-input-queue-on-a-unix-system). If you ask a slightly different question, *how can I remove data from the STDIN stream buffer of the same TTY session*, the answer is simple: type Ctrl-Z, which will suspend the command and flush input, then `fg` to continue it.

Comment: Wow, i didn't realize Ctl-Z would also flush the input buffer of a running process. Think i will test this... Yeah hopefully you know what I want to do from the question, I was not sure what the best way to frame the question honestly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your tty has the `noflsh` flag turned off - you can check with

```
stty -a < /dev/pts/whatever | grep -e -noflsh
```

from another tty, but the default is that it's turned off - then typing the interrupt, quit, or suspend character will flush the input queue. So if you type <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>, then `fg`, it will suspend the currently running command, flush the input, then resume the command.

Comment: I just checked a few different machines of mine with the `stty` command. The `grep` on one of my machines returned with the following: `isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt`... does that mean that the `-noflsh` flag is on or off?

Comment: `-noflsh` means that it's off, so you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should send SIGSTOP to bash in order to prevent it from doing anything, and after finishing your task send SIGKILL to bash.

Note that SIGSTOP prevents bash from waiting for your task to be finished, and you'll get zombie. After SIGKILL init will reparent your task, and zombie will disappear.

Comment: Also you may attach to bash process using gdb -p PID and forcely close stdin file descriptor with "p close(0)" command.

Comment: So just testing the first suggestion, I don't seem to be able to stop one instance of bash from receiving commands with `kill -18 PID` from another instance of bash where `PID` is the process id of the instance i want to stop. I can still type in commands and the first instance evaluates them.

Comment: As for the `gdb` stuff, I was really hoping for something more elegant... I found that method, but the GNU Project Debugger seems a bit overkill to do this. I don't have that installed on any of my machines.

Comment: SIGSTOP is 19th signal, not 18th. If bash runs under another user, consider using sudo.

Comment: Yeah i had a typo in the comment, i edited it and fixed that, the other instance of bash is running under the same user. `sudo` doesn't seem to make a difference.