# Why does the terminal echo keystrokes when commands are running?

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, stty

I was recently running `tail -f` on a log file of a server that was running, trying to diagnose a bug, when I accidentally bumped the keyboard and typed some characters. They got mixed in with the output of the log, with no way to tell which was which. I have had similarly annoying things happen to me countless times, and I'm sure it has happened to many other people here.

So my question is this: **why does the shell (or terminal, or whatever is doing it) ambiguously mix keyboard input with command output?**

I am not asking for a practical solution to an immediate problem. I can maybe figure out some way to make the shell run `stty -echo` when a command is run and `stty echo` when it finishes. But I want to know the rationale behind designing the terminal like this. Is there some practical purpose? Or is it something done only for compatibility reasons, or something that wasn't given much thought at all?

Comment: [It has been given a fair amount of thought over a lot of years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_(computing)).

Comment: Since the rest of the TTY system seems like a good design, I'm guessing this feature is there on purpose, and that purpose is to allow type-ahead. PDP-11s probably took a lot of time waiting for disk or tape input, so type-ahead would have been a real benefit.

Comment: I edited the title for clarity, but this is a really good as asked. If there is any confusion about whether it is the shell or it is the terminal, rest-assured that it is the terminal. The shell is not involved at that point. You *can* make the shell echo *its* input to stderr with `set -v`, though.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `less +F somefile` provides similar functionality to `tail -f somefile` except that (accidentally) typed keystrokes will not `echo` to the screen.

Comment: See this answer:  [the Unix creators designed it that way](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178989/is-it-safe-to-type-another-command-into-stdin-while-the-previous-command-is-writ/179002#179002) and nobody has decided it's worth changing the tty i/o system to do otherwise.

Comment: I did once, a long time ago, use / see / or dream about, I can not remember, a terminal that had 2 sections: the lower part was where it echoed keyboard input. The upper part was where all output went.

Comment: @richard Apollo/Domain, maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People usually want to see what they're typing (unless it's a password) :-)

The terminal accepts input at any time, and buffers it until an application reads it. More than that, when the tty is in *cooked* mode, the kernel buffers whole lines at a time and provides some rudimentary line editing functionality that allow you to kill the entire buffered line (default binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> and backspace. During the time that the line is being entered and edited and until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, applications reading from the terminal read nothing at all.

The tty functionality in the kernel does not and can not know if and when an application like `tail` is planning to produce output on the terminal, so it would not be able to somehow... cancel (?) line editing during such times and only during such times.

Anyway, being able to prepare the next line for the shell while something else is still busy running on the terminal and the shell is not yet ready to read that command is a *feature*, not a bug, so I wouldn't advocate removing it. Maybe not so useful for `tail` (which will never terminate on its own), but pre-typing the next command during a long-running `cp` or `make` (for example), and even editing that command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>, all before the shell gets ahold of it, is a common thing to do. [Timothy Martin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/46592/timothy-martin) wrote in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210628/why-does-the-terminal-echo-keystrokes-when-commands-are-running#comment356623_210628):

> It is worth mentioning that `less +F somefile` provides similar functionality to `tail -f somefile` except that (accidentally) typed keystrokes will not `echo` to the screen.

Yeah, but `less` not only prevents those characters from being echoed, but it also *eats* them, so they are not available to the next application that wants to read them!

Finally, there is one more reason:

In historical times (before my time!) terminals with local echo were common. That is, the terminal (usually in hardware) would echo the characters you typed locally while also sending them down the serial line. This is useful for giving the user quick feedback even if there was lots of latency over the conection to the UNIX system (think [300 baud modem](http://img403.imageshack.us/img403/3111/acousticcoupler.jpg) dialing up a terminal server with auto-telnet to a slow UNIX system over a [token ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_ring) network — or whatever).

If you have a terminal with local echo, then you want `stty -echo` at all times on the UNIX server to which you are connected. The result is approximately the same as a terminak *without* local echo (the common kind today) and `stty echo` enabled. So from that point of view, `stty echo`'s job is to echo charatcers immediately as soon as they are received, regardless of what software is running, in emulation of what would happen on a terminal with local echo.

(By the way, if you have a terminal with local echo, you can't hide your password.)

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, if you want to disable tty device local `echo` for a specific command, you can do:

```
STTY=-echo a-specific-command
```

`zsh` will apply the specific settings (by calling `stty`) and restore them when the command terminates.

Of course, you'll probably  only want to do that for applications that don't read from the tty device.