# making it so keys typed on stdin aren't echo'd back out

Tags: bash, stdin

If I do `cat > filename.ext` and then type in a bunch of text that text will (1) be echo'd onto the screen as I type it in and (2) appear in filename.ext.

That's okay if I'm doing that for text files but it's more problematic if I'm doing it for binary files because strange things can happen as discussed in https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-puttyputty .

So any ideas how I might be able to make it so that keys that I type aren't echo'd back to the screen?

Comment: I'm confused, are you typing input or `cat`ing binary files?

Comment: If you create a file by using cat and typing input it wont be a binary file so I just don't see any issue here

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/210628/117549

Comment: @jesse_b - I'm using an SSH library to dump the contents of a binary file into stdin. eg. `$ssh->exec('cat > filename.txt'); $ssh->write(file_get_contents('filename.ext'))`. ie. I'm not using iTerm nor am I using PuTTY (both of which would presumably limit stdin to characters on the keyboard) but rather, I'm using an SSH library, which affords me more fine tuned control over what's being sent.

Comment: Your question should really mention that you are writing an incredibly fragile file transfer mechanism, where the recipient end is `cat` with the terminal in canonical mode.  There are reasons that ZMODEM and others worked as they did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, turn echo off in the ttys settings. From the shell you can do that with `stty -echo`:

```
(g=$(stty -g); stty -echo; cat > outfile; stty "$g")
<type blindly, finish by Enter, Control-D>
```

Comment: When I do `ssh localhost '(g=$(stty -g); stty -echo; cat > outfile2; stty "$g")'` I get a `stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device` error. Any idea what's up with that?

Comment: use the `-t` option to force ssh to allocate a pseudo-tty; `ssh` will only do that by default when it's used with no `command` argument.

Comment: you may need TWO `-t` (`ssh -tt`) if the stdin of the ssh command is not a tty.